# Textbox validation 2 char and 2 integer

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

i need to validate textbox1 as 2 alphabets and 2integer only i.e) ab11

how i can set it my text box only accept 2 chars and 2 integers.

Please help me...

Comment: Please post here the things you tried..

Comment: I doesn't know how to do this ... i have tried only if it's empty show a message box...

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

if:

```
string myString = textbox1.Text;
```

Then to validate:

```
If (Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}$")))
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Regex is a class..you need to add reference to System.Text.RegularExpressions for it to work...

Comment: i have added regular expression namespace. I have given the input abcd in text box it allows to accept after adding the above piece of code

Comment: geez...this is how your code should look for it to work:private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (textBox3.Text.Trim().Length != 0) { string myString = textBox3.Text; if (!Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}$")){MessageBox.Show("Given Format not valid"); } } else { MessageBox.Show("Given Format not valid"); }

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void textBox2_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var cn = textBox2.Text.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).Count();
        var cd = textBox2.Text.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c)).Count();
        if (cn >= 2 && cd >= 2)
        {
            //Success, Do Stuff
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb=sender as TextBox;
    string text=tb.Text;

    switch (text.Length)
    { 
        case 1:
            if (!char.IsLetter(text[0]))
                tb.Text = "";
            break;
        case 2:
            if (!char.IsLetter(text[1]))
                tb.Text = text.Remove(1);
            break;
        case 3: 
            if (!char.IsNumber(text[2]))
                tb.Text = text.Remove(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            if (!char.IsNumber(text[3]))
                tb.Text = text.Remove(3);
            break;
        default:
            if(text.Length>4)
                tb.Text = text.Substring(0, 4);
            break;
    }
    textBox1.Select(tb.Text.Length, 0);
}
```

Comment: Isletter, Isnumber are not listed. Do i need to add any namespace to listed this ?

Comment: No special namespace required.`using System;` will be enough.

Comment: Are you using WindowsForms?

Comment: can we set a masked text box for the above inputs

Comment: Did not tested. But my guess is it should work. Are you able to get `Isletter`, `Isnumber` now?Or still having problem?

Comment: Am not able to get isletter or isnumber. am using masked text box and customized it for AB99. Now the problem is if masked textboxis empty should give a error but it doesn't give a error

Comment: when you type `System.Char.IsNumber('1');` what is the error message you get?

Comment: If user enters AB<space><number> || AB<number><space> ||AB<Space><space> it should give an error. But it doesn't throw any error

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = textBox1.Text;
if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^(([A-Z]|[a-z])([A-Z]|[a-z])\d\d)$"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Valid");
}
```

Reference: [Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)